# Background thread to download image and set to image view

Tags: windows-phone-8, uiimage, backgroundworker

In my windows phone 8 application, i have one image view, by default it is set to local static image.

```
<Image  x:Name="advImage"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/banner.jpg" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Now after loading the page, **I want to get the original image from the server and should be replace the above static image.** This task should be done in background via thread so that the user interface should not be blocked. I don't want to display any progress bar while downloading the image.

I'm new to windows phone 8. Please provide your solutions to the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need too use databinding(binding)

```
<Image  x:Name="advImage"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="'Binding Image,mode=twoway" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

    private string _image;
    public string Image{
    get
        {
            return m_IconPath;
        }
        set
        {
                _IconPath = value;
                PropertyChanged ("IconPath");
        }
    }
```

Now when your user is connected get your server image and set the property Image.

Comment: Could you pleas tell me in clear, how to get the image from the server and set the property image because i'm new to windows phone 8 development.

Comment: Explaim me what do you want to do with your application?Your server (development) is finish?
For set property :
go to constructor class and :
public constructorName(){
 Image = getServeurImage();
}

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx